# Batch Save to MongoDB C# Driver

Tags: c#, .net, mongodb

I am having difficulty batch saving MongoDB documents using the C# driver. Here's sample code that inserts a Document with a GUID BsonID. Saving one at a time works. If I insert the documents into a list and use the save command it fails with an *"Save can only be used with documents that have an Id."* error. Any thoughts?

```
var autolookuplist = new List<BsonDocument>();
            Parallel.ForEach(docs, webdoc =>
                {
                    lock (autolookuplist)
                    {
                        autoID++;
                        var hold = new APAUtoIDGuidLookup() {AutoIncrementID = autoID, ID = webdoc.ID};
                      autolookuplist.Add(hold.ToBsonDocument());
                    }

                  //this works
                 //   idcollection.Save(new APAUtoIDGuidLookup() { AutoIncrementID = autoID, ID = webdoc.ID });
                });


          //this doesn't work
          idcollection.Save(autolookuplist);
```

here's the document class

```
public class  APAUtoIDGuidLookup
{
    [BsonId]
    public Guid ID { get; set; }
    public int AutoIncrementID { get; set; }
}
```

Update:
**It doesn't look like MongoDB supports batch updates.**

Comment: An unrelated observation: you are using `Parallel.ForEach` and you are immediately synchronizing your access to the `autolookuplist` via the `lock` statement. This doesn't make much sense or am I missing something?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't do a batch save, but you can do a batch insert.

```
idcollection.InsertBatch(autolookuplist);
```

Comment: Thanks, I thought about that, but I am trying to update the collection. I guess I could delete and insert the data. The driver is supposed to support what I am doing (according to the overloads on the method). 
  `Summary:
Saves a document to this collection. The document must have an identifiable Id field. Based on the value of the Id field Save will perform either an Insert or an Update.`

Comment: As you are assigning ID's to your objects by yourself try using ObjectID and not BsonID attribute.  Also I have found that just looping the list and calling collection.Save works great with large lists.

Comment: Yes I am assigning the Id values manually (it's really an association from another table). They are Guids, and work pretty well one at a time. When this server goes into production it will be under heavy load (using EC2 I/O) so I want to minimize the cost of updates.

Comment: You have correctly quoted the document for Save.  Notice that it doesn't say it will save more than one, but rather will only save one.  You aren't passing save a document, but rather a list of documents.  This won't work.  As AliK, said, you should just loop the list and call Save on each one individually.

Comment: You are more familiar with the product then I am, but the overload allows passing a List<BsonDocument>. That means it should save the list, right?